# Celery: Error in connecting to RabbitMQ Server

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

I am starting to use celery by following this ["First Steps with Celery"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).
I exactly used the tasks.py indicated on that link.
However when I ran the task using,

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I am getting this error:

```
[2014-09-16 20:52:57,427: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed. Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

The rabbitmq server is for sure running and below is the snippet of the log regarding the error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:09 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.235.0> from 127.0.0.1:58162
{channel0_error,starting,
            {amqp_error,access_refused,
                        "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                        'connection.start_ok'}}

=INFO REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:09 ===
closing TCP connection <0.235.0> from 127.0.0.1:58162

=INFO REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:15 ===
accepted TCP connection on [::]:5672 from 127.0.0.1:58163

=INFO REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:15 ===
starting TCP connection <0.239.0> from 127.0.0.1:58163

=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:18 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.239.0> from 127.0.0.1:58163
{channel0_error,starting,
            {amqp_error,access_refused,
                        "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                        'connection.start_ok'}}

=INFO REPORT==== 16-Sep-2014::20:53:18 ===
closing TCP connection <0.239.0> from 127.0.0.1:58163
```

With this, I did the following to ensure that the 'guest' user has permissions to / vhost:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / guest ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

And then I reloaded/restarted rabbitmq service to make sure the changes will take effect,
then ran the task again. However, the error is still the same.

I even tried creating a different vhost (jm-vhost) and user (jm-user1) and set the permission again to allow all:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost jm-vhost
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user jm-user1 ""   --> "" to make it passwordless (is this correct?)
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /jm-vhost jm-user1 ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

And then modified tasks.py to this:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://jm-user1@localhost//jm-vhost')
```

But when I started the tasks, still, I get the same error.
How should I resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to resolve this (for those who have and will have the same issue) by doing the following.

I recreated the user I mentioned on my question, but this time with a password. Like this:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user jm-user1 sample
```

Then I set the permissions again with this:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p jm-vhost jm-user1 ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Restarted rabbitmq server to make sure the changes take effect and made modifications to tasks.py:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://jm-user1:sample@localhost/jm-vhost')
```

When I ran,

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

it worked :).

Hopefully, this will be of help to others.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Another thing I've found is that if you want to do this programmatically, use this syntax, just like this: subprocess.call(['rabbitmqctl', 'set_permissions', '-p', 'vhost_name', 'joe_user', '.*', '.*', '.*'])

Comment: It definitely helped me. Thanks!

Comment: My problem was that my password had a bracket and a dollar sign in it.  I removed those characters and everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

The `broker_url` has the format:

```
transport://userid:password@hostname:port/virtual_host
```

> http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-url